# Variable expansion in Windows containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

Consider the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM alpine:latest
ARG MY_VAR="my value"
RUN echo $MY_VAR
```

When building the container, part of the output is `[2/2] RUN echo my value`, so the variable `$MY_VAR` has been expanded to the value `my value` in the `RUN` command.

Now, I switch to a Windows container, and a similar `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
ARG MY_VAR="my value"
RUN echo $MY_VAR
```

When building the Windows container, part of the output is `Step 3/3 : RUN echo $MY_VAR`, so the variable has not been expanded!

How can I enable variable expansion in Windows containers?

Comment: Environment variables are handled differently in windows, might be worth reading: https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-weekly-dockerfile-14-environment-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when using batch-style notation for environment variables!

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
ARG MY_VAR="my value"
RUN echo %MY_VAR%
```

Comment: Variable expansion is done by the shell and Windows containers run a different shell than Linux containers, so you need to use Windows shell syntax.